# Audit who deployed SQL database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, audit-logging, audit-trail

Through SSMS, connecting to my on prem server, you can right click a database, select tasks and "DEPLOY DATABASE TO MICROSOFT AZURE SQL DATABASE".  Is there a way to log/audit who did this from my on prem server?

After doing this, I've checked the SQL Server logs and do not see any entries for this.

Thanks!

Comment: This process creates a bacpac file on my local machine.  Does SQL log who created a bacpac file?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to investigate the logs using power-BI content pack refer below link.
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/fr-be/blog/monitor-azure-audit-logs-with-power-bi/

You can also use Azure Activity Log API to check the resource changes refer API link below for details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activity-logs/list?tabs=HTTP

[image: Example screenshot containing fields available for analysis]

Comment: My on prem is not Azure.

Comment: @ScottD I think the point is that if it was deployed to Azure, then the Azure logs could potentially tell you who deployed it to Azure. Whether the deployment was done from on prem or in another cloud resource, the Azure logs should tell you who created those objects in Azure.

Comment: i agree with Trent

Comment: @Trenton-ftw, understandable.  What if a developer copied my on prem database to their azure environment that I have no control over and can't view their logs?  Is that copy logged in transaction files or anywhere on my machine?  I've also found that if a developer was to create a dacpac file through Export Data Tier Application, I don't see it logged in the SQL logs.  Thanks for your help!